# Run-time error '3704':Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to run code in VBA and I am getting the following error

"Run-time error '3704':Operation is not allowed when the object is closed."

I am running a SQL query and when running it I get this error, but if I run a much simpler SQL query it works with no issue.

```vb
Sub macro()

Dim entry as String, query As string , ostatni_rzad As Integer, rw_name As String Dim data_source As String
Dim initial_catalog As String
Dim server_for_DE As String
Dim data_source_for_DE As String

query = "Use database SET NOCOUNT ON Declare  Set @valueId = 139 set @matruirtyPeriodInt = 677 
Set @curveIdList = char(39)+ '432' + char(39) + ',' + char(39) +  '432433424' + Char(39)Set @EffectiveDate = '01/01/2001' 
Set @bondEquivalentEffectiveDate = '01/01/2001' Set @simulationName = 'mysimulation' Select  top 1       @simulationId = simulationId,       @batchLoadId = BatchloadId 
From     myserver with(nolock) Where  [name] = @simulationName  And   Effectivedate = @EffectiveDate  Order by startDate desc 
Select  top 1 @bondEquiValentsimulationId = simulationId ,  @durationEquiValentBatchLoadId = BatchloadId From   myserver with (nolock) 
Where    [name] = @bondEquivalentSimulationName and  Effectivedate =  @bondEquivalentEffectiveDate Order by  startDate desc   Select  @linkServerName = LinkServerName ,  @databaseName = DatabaseName 
From   myserver L with (nolock)Left    Outer Join  myserver R with (nolock) 
On     L.DatabaseId = R.simulationStorageDatabaseId Where R.simulationId = @simulationId;  
WITH cte AS 

(SELECT    x,y,z,w,u,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) AS rn   From mybase with (nolock) Where simulationid = @bondEquiValentsimulationId , 

GROUP BY x,y,z,w,u) 


Select * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
"

entry = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=" & data_source & ";Initial Catalog=" & initial_catalog & ";Integrated Security=SSPI"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With Cn
    .CommandTimeout = kpkp 'fds
    .Open dccurnx
    End With

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rs
            .ActiveConnection = Cn

            .Open query
End With

   ostatni_rzad = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Row - 1 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(ostatni_rzad + 1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

And in this last line is where I get the error

Comment: Try checking the connection's Errors collection for information about any problems with your SQL (and I'd suspect there will be at least one)

Comment: Why you don't you use stored procedure?

Comment: Try using a `Command` instead. Then you can do `Set rs = cmd.Execute`, and you can easily parameterize your query without needing to concatenate parts of the SQL command string. That said, JohnyL has a point: invoking a stored procedure would make much less SQL to debug in an editor that's clearly not made for this.

Comment: Does it work if you move the `CopyFromRecordset` call into the `With rs` block? Make sure you `CopyFromRecordset` *before* you ever invoke `rs.Close`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` anywhere in the SQL query command. This fixed it for me.